# How to run specifications based on the order of the tags inputtted

Tags: getgauge

Example:
- Consider I have two specs (Spec 1 and Spec 2).
- In both the specs I have few scenarios and each scenario has a tag representing the stages it has to run. Say spec1 has scenarios relevant to "STAGE_1" and "STAGE_2". And same is the case in "Spec 2".

- Now, I want to run all scenarios across all specifications (spec 1 and spec 2) in a particular order.
- The order I want is 
  a. Run all the "STAGE1" scenarios first and then
  b. Run all the "STAGE2" scenarios.

Further Constraints:
I do have requirement to place these in a seperate specification because
- I may choose to run at a specification without bothering the stage level sorting
- I also want the "STAGE1" to set some data in the store, which can be consumed by the steps in the next stage say "STAGE2".

So, In effect, I see my requirement is to have a command something like

gauge run specs -tags="STAGE1 | STAGE2"

but expect gauge to sort all "STAGE1" scenarios first to execute and then execute all the STAGE2 scenarios next.

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Gauge does not consider tags for order of specs. Furthermore, in your example you have listed a tag expression, which can be hard to determine order from. ex. if you did `!STAGE1`, all it tells gauge is to ignore the tag, it becomes difficult to determine the order.

Instead if you passed in a list of spec files or directories, Gauge will try to preserve the order of execution.

By default, gauge does not guarantee any order. You'll have to use `--sort` flag with `gauge run`. Ref: https://manpage.gauge.org/gauge_run.html